# Rendering Errors on Comment Form Nested in Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a post model and on that post's Show view, I have a Comment form with my error output partial. However, I'm not sure how to reder the errors appropriately since I don't have a standalone New action for comments, just a create.

For simple models I have been using this pattern for my create statement:

```
def create

    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save       
        flash[:success] = "You've added a post!"
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

How can I make the else portion of this pattern work when I need it to render the comment errors on the post page? When I use the exact pattern "render 'new'" as above, it takes me to my stubbed "Find me in app/views/comments/new.html.erb" page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `render @post` instead of `render 'new'`.

Comment: Looks like I get the html output of my _story.html.erb rendered. It actually shows the markup on the page, oddly.

Comment: I have tried "render :show" as well as "render @post :show" neither work and both throw errors.